# How to track ycor of a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a virtual manometer on Net Logo. The manometer has fluid (which is turtle that moves upward as "go" is pressed) inside it and I want Net Logo to either monitor the y cor of that fluid or plot that height. 
Is it possible? I am a beginner so any kind of assistance will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Every turtle has a ycor attribute which can be extracted like `[ycor] of turtle` where turtle is the turtle you are trying to get the ycor from. So, to answer your question: Yes.

You may want to look into Plotting Example in the models library which plots the xcor and ycor with respect to time.